# dBWriteTable cannot write more than one record (with NA) into into SQL Server table

Tags: r, sql-server, jdbc, datatable, rjdbc

I am using RJDBC and dbWriteTable to write a data.table into an existing SQL Server database table.
Here is my sample data: mtcars

After I get connection to DB, I am using dbWriteTable to create a DB table "mtcars".

dbWriteTable(conn, "mtcars", mtcars[1:5, ])

Next use append=T to insert two rows:
dbWriteTable(conn.pre.alg, "mtcars",mtcars[6:7, ], append = T)

Then I set a NA in a row:
mtcars[8, 2] = NA

I can insert the record without any problem.
dbWriteTable(conn.pre.alg, "mtcars",mtcars[8, ], append = T)

But when I set NA in a row and try to insert two rows:
mtcars[9:10, 2] = NA
dbWriteTable(conn.pre.alg, "mtcars",mtcars[9:10, ], append = T)

I get an error:
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 4 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.)

I tried to set field.types, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Why not RODBC?  What JDBC driver?

Comment: Can you try to set as NULL instead of NA?

Comment: I tried to set NULL to mtcars[11:12, 2] = NULL, but I got this error: Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

Comment: I have never used ODBC. I have used JDBC. But this time, with R, it is not working properly with NA.

Comment: I am using the latest R and here is the sessionInfo()

Comment: R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
Matrix products: default
....
other attached packages:
[1] R.utils_2.11.0    R.oo_1.24.0       R.methodsS3_1.8.1 data.table_1.14.2 RJDBC_0.2-8       rJava_1.0-5      
[7] DBI_1.1.1